# TSQL query searching for multiple keywords across multiple fields

Tags: t-sql

I am looking for assistance in improving the search capability of my webstore. I have tried multiple methods without success. I sell diecast cars, and am missing out opportunities of products being displayed to the customer due to search query shortcomings.

My database contains a products table with productids, names and descriptions, and another table containing product "tags" mapped to the productids (a product can have multiple tags mapped).

An example search might be "1/18 scale". If I have that exact value in [name], [description], or [tag] (in the tag map table) the search works fine. My product descriptions all have the scale in "1:18" format instead of "1/18" format, thus I created tags for all the products with the '1/18" format.

But say a customer searches for "1/18 chrysler". I have way too many combinations to create tags for everything.

Is there a way to search for results where any of those fields contains any of those terms, inclusive? In other words, if [Name], [Description] or [tag] contains "1/18" AND [Name], [Description] or [tag] contains "chrysler"?
in a case like this, I would like to match the "1/18" in the [tag] field, and the "chrysler" in the [Description] or [name] field.

Note that I have a Full Text Index on both tables.

Comment: You're looking for [Full-Text Search feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Yes, I already have Full Text indexing set up. But I am unsure of the TSQL to make it work in my instance (some keywords may be in one field, but other keywords in another field)

Comment: Not sure what you have a problem with: "A full-text index includes one or more character-based columns in a table".

Comment: Have you tried something like `CONTAINS([NAME],'1/18 AND chrysler') OR CONTAINS([Description],'1/18 AND chrysler')`?

Comment: bbaird - that would work if both '1/18' and 'chrysler' were in a single field I am searching against. what I am needing is if '1/18' is in a field AND 'chrysler' was in a field, but not necessarily both in the same field.

Comment: Have you tried using [FREETEXT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/freetext-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) instead to search across multiple columns?

Comment: sort of.. haven't figured out how to structure the freetext query correctly.  Also, I am dealing with fields in multiple tables.  I keep getting way too many false positives (matches one term, over all or the other, or both). I need to restrict results on ALL keywords being present but not all keywords in the same field.

Comment: couldn't you build a denormalized table or maybe an indexed view where you concatenate all the possible search fields together ? Then put the fulltext index on that & do your fulltext searches.

Comment: I tried that Mo64, but since the at least 1 field is in another table, requires a LEFT JOIN, can't create an indexed view.

Answer (score 0):

My search stored procedure is very extensive and complicated. Part of it is building a long sql query string with several unions, then executing that sql statement to put matching items into a temp table, then final filtering on that table. I didn't write the stored procedure (it came with nopcommerce).

I ended up writing a scalar function that builds and returns an additional union statement to add to the rest of the stored procedures sql statement. In my function, I STRING_SPLIT the passed keywords, splitting by spaces so I can use a cursor, loop over each keyword and  add a ( CONTAINS(field1, @keyword) OR CONTAINS(field2, @keword) ) for each @keyword with each CONTAINS ANDed with the the next and so forth.

Probably not the best way to work it, but appears to work quite well, no false positives, and seems pretty fast.